# Update multiple records in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have records in mysql database. What I need to know if how to update all ACR001 and SUP-001 at once?

```
id | cat_code | item_code  
-------------------------
1  | ACR001   | SUP-001
2  | ACR001   | SUP-001
3  | ACR001   | SUP-001
4  | ACR001   | SUP-001
5  | BCR001   | COM-001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple update query

```
UPDATE table SET cat_code = 'NEWVALUE', item_code = 'NEWVALUE' WHERE cat_code = 'ACR001' AND item_code = 'SUP-001'
```

Comment: Try it @user3462269 Report your errors to the person who gave you the answer, I have nothing to do with this past this point.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the field you need to update:

```
UPDATE table SET `Field_name`= 'new_value' WHERE cat_code = 'ACR001' AND item_code = 'SUP-001'
```

This query will update all records with the value of `Field_name' depending on the value of`new_value` where cat_code = 'ACR001' and if item_code = 'SUP-001'